# how can i simplify crud

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi i would like to simplify my code on the crud messagebox. I currently have almost 20 over pages of CRUD forms with 4 buttons of create, update delete and reset. How do i simplify this to become a user control? so that i don have to keep writting "Save successfully", "sorry, error",....

my Code

```
 protected override void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!validateBeforeSave()) return;

        if (MessageBox.Show(MessageManager.SaveAsk, "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            try
            {                  
                BindValueToObject();                   

                if (Convert.ToInt32(lblEmpId.Text) == 0)
                {
                    user.Add();
                    ResetAfterSave(true, user.Id);
                    base.Success = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    user.Update();
                    ResetAfterSave(false, user.Id);
                    base.Success = true;
                }
                base.btnSave_Click(this, null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(typeof(UsersForm), ex.ToString());
                base.Success = false;
                base.btnSave_Click(this, null);
            }
        }
    }
    protected override void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (null == dgUser.CurrentRow) return;
        user.Id = (int)dgUser.SelectedRows[0].Cells["empId"].Value;

        try
        {
            if ((MessageBox.Show(MessageManager.DeleteAsk, "Are you sure to delete?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes))
            {
                user.Delete();
                ResetAfterSave(false, 0);
                base.Success = true;
                base.btnDelete_Click(this, null);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            base.Success = false;
            base.btnDelete_Click(this, null);
        }
    }
```

The base.btnSave_Click(this, null); is calling this below where i pass in the flag.

```
 protected virtual void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.success)
            MessageBox.Show(MessageManager.SaveSuccess, "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(MessageManager.SaveFailed, "Fail to save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            return;
        }
    }
```

I felt very annoying of rewriting this over and over again.

Comment: Some code would be nice to demonstrate what exactly it is you are doing.

Comment: I think that depends on how u design ur UI. For me, usually I link retrieve with delete and update. Normally select is done on load, then users can do filter, or click on those they want to update or delete. These 3 comes together in 1 page. Insert function will be in the form of popup, where a new UI is shown

Comment: I would think a page with CRUD without pop up is better. It would help u to visualize a page with a gridview on the left and some controls on the right e.g. textbox.. Clicking on the gridview will display those data to the controls on the right.

Comment: @ Woot4Moo: Hi i have added the code. please advice

Comment: @belinq: Try encapsulating repeating methods.

Comment: @Niraj Doshi: Thanks for the reply. What do u meant by encapsulating repeating modules?

Comment: @belinq: Sorry I meant Extracting not Encapsulating..fields can be encapsulated while methods are extracted. You can select this option from Refactor > Extract Method. Write these methods in main form and make them public. Then utilize them throughout the application.

Comment: what's about MessageManager source code?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I meant Extracting not Encapsulating..fields can be encapsulated while methods are extracted. You can select this option from Refactor > Extract Method. Write these methods in main form and make them public. Then utilize them throughout the application.

I have a better option than that, but I would like to correct myself if it is hazardous to do so.

What we do is we declare the event handler public in the main form.

for e.g.

```
public virtual void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.success)
            MessageBox.Show(MessageManager.SaveSuccess, "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(MessageManager.SaveFailed, "Fail to save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Now, Select any of the Save button in any of your form , go to properties > Events > and select btnSave_Click. You can use the same method throughout your software, provided that you have same code to run everywhere.